# Put all unique words from column into new dataset

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

Get unique words from column and put them in new column

I tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
query=list(train['doc_text'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().unique())
```

Here’s an example of data:

```
Train
Row             Doc_text                 Count
0             this is a book               4
1             my taylor is rich            4 
2             apple a day                  3
```

Here’s an example of expected output:

```
Dfnew
Row         Uniquewords
0            this
1            is
2            a
3            book
4            my 
5            taylor
6            rich
7            apple
8            day
```

I would like to get the words in a list, and then be able to save this list as a new dataset.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar any idea? your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @pault may I know why it is off-topic? I would like to improve. Thanks

Comment: closed as off-topic but yet received 2 positive votes, may I know what was wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
unique_list = []
for i in df['Uniquewords']:
    [unique_list.append(word) for word in i.split() if word not in unique_list]
```

You can use this `unique_list` or you can write this list to a dataframe.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(unique_list, columns=['Unique_words'])
```

Comment: Thank you @Sumanth

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need something like below:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(train['doc_text'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().unique(),\
                columns=['Uniquewords']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Row'})
print(df_new)

   Row Uniquewords
0    0        this
1    1          is
2    2           a
3    3        book
4    4          my
5    5      taylor
6    6        rich
7    7       apple
8    8         day
```